# Mongo-DB update query

Tags: sql, database, mongodb

I want to change my location field in my existing MongoDB database from:

C01-S14-D05 --> Container01-Shelf14

I need to do this for thousands of documents, so I need a quick way to do this.
I need to keep the numbers container and shelf numbers stored in variables, and then I need to update the field to the new format. (note I'm completely getting rid of D05 (drawer 5))

Comment: Would you show an example document before and after the change you are looking for?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The more information you can provide in the question the better we are going to be able to assist. This answer assumes that your documents have an existing structure similar to the following:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  location: "C01-S14-D05"
}
```

This answer also assumes that each identifier has a single letter and then two digits. If so, then a solution similar to the following should work or will at least serve as a good starting point:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $addFields: {
      location: {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            vals: {
              $split: [ "$location", "-" ]
            }
          },
          in: {
            "$concat": [
              "Container",
              {
                "$substr": [
                  { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$$vals", 0 ] },
                  1,
                  2
                ]
              },
              "-Shelf",
              {
                "$substr": [
                  { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$$vals", 1 ] },
                  1,
                  2
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground demonstration here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4-4dVv7mXXT)